# Exporting MongoDB database via Java interface?

Tags: java, mongodb, import, export

If you search for Mongo and export you only find documentations and topics about the `mongoexport` and `mongoimport` commands.

But I only access Mongo via it's Java interface, therefore I see two major problems:

1. Both tools are native executables - but Java is platform independent
2. They have to be installed on the machine or you have to include all versions for all platforms in the Java program.

Therefore I want to avoid mongoexport/mongoimport and use a Java-only export/import. Please do not post answers using Runtime.getRuntime() or ProcessBuilder.

Do somebody have plain Java code for exporting/importing a complete mongo database with all collections into JSON, BSON or a similar format?

Comment: This is far too broad for StackOverflow. It's not clear why you'd want to duplicate existing functionality, or where you couldn't get it working on your own.